# QGIS (Mis)Detecting Escape Characters in SLD files

Tags: qgis

Okay, I am just running into some trouble with the string literal functionality with QGIS's rule based styling.

For example I have an attribute called LITH that equals 'BAS\b'. The rule where LITH = 'BAS\b' does not work however as the escape character is not being ignored.

How would I go about ignoring the escape character in QGIS? If I was using c# I could use @'BAS\b', if I was using XML I would use the ![] tags.

I am loading these rules from a SLD file, but the symbology is incorrect in places due to the escape character not being ignored.

Comment: SLD is an XML file

Comment: I have edited title and last paragraph for more reference to SLD. The situation where I have run into the problem of escape characters is not only when loading from SLD files, it can be encountered using field calculator as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QGIS expression engine doesn't have string literals...(yet)

You will just have to escape the escape with `\\`

So:

```
LITH = 'BAS\b'
```

Comment: PostgreSQL has `quote_literal` which I could add. Although I can't add it to QGIS 2.0 because of feature freeze but I can add it to my extra expression functions plugin https://github.com/NathanW2/qgsexpressionsplus which you can use in QGIS 2.0

Comment: Ah okay, I just parsed the XML (SLD) and inserted extra back slashes.

Comment: Interestingly stack overflow needs three backslashes to display two backslashes, which is what I assume is in your answer.

Comment: You need to wrap it in ` ` to treat it as literal.